# Why am I getting "unrecognised argument to dateFromString: 'format'" despite having db version >3.6 which supports the aggregation

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregate

I have some dates that are string formatted like this in chats:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("2bfd5d45348ef655b5236d93"),
"status" : "closed",
"context" : "Chats",
"chats" : {
    "time_initialized" : "2019-02-20T17:35:39.960284505Z",
    "time_responded" : "2019-02-20T17:42:06.691469546Z",
    "time_closed" : "2019-02-20T17:44:10.158421784Z"
}
```

My DB version in mongo is 3.6.5:

[image]

In the Mongo documentation, you can see below that the function dateFromString is supported:

[image]

Here's my code that is failing with:

**"errmsg" : "Unrecognized argument to $dateFromString: format"**

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
   {$match: {"context": "Chats", "status": "closed", 
   "chats.time_closed": {$exists: true}}},

   {$unwind: "$chats"},

  {$project: {chats:1, _id: 1, status: 1, 
  initialised_closed_duration: 
      {$divide: [
          {$subtract: [
              {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$chats.time_closed", format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000000000Z"}},{$dateFromString: {dateString: "$chats.time_initialized", format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000000000Z"}}]},60000]}}},
 {$limit: 5}]).pretty()
```

The point of my query is to get the date a chat is initialised and then closed, and work out the duration in minutes (hence dividing the millisecond date difference by 60,000)

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator was added in 3.6 but its signature changed in v4.

There was no "format" argument back in v3.6. The documentation for this version is available at https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/

Comment: Shit, I see what you mean. How frustrating. So I can't specify a format. Thanks though, i'll do some string processing before passing it to the dateFromString function