# How to convert string to Date in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoid, pymongo

I have found lot of answers in `stackoverflow` but nothing has fixed me. I have `collection` which looks like this

```
#DB Name: test 
#Collection Name: firstcollection

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8b51e80eeb1c27ce119e52"), 
    "url" : "http://192.168.1.37/second.html", 
    "browser" : "Netscape", 
    "uniqueId" : "dd0c76b1-77c7-445a-8bcd-e58cb239507e", 
    "ip" : " 162.158.166.103", 
    "date" : "25/09/2019 16:37:56"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8b51e80eeb1c27ce119e62"), 
    "url" : "http://192.168.1.37/second.html", 
    "browser" : "Netscape", 
    "uniqueId" : "c3a3c5f8-23a8-4626-9b43-b5a95fb02597", 
    "ip" : " 172.69.134.115", 
    "date" : "25/09/2019 16:38:13"
}
```

In here, I want to Convert my `date` which is in the form of `String` to `Date` format. I tried this code

```
> db.firstcollection.aggregate([
...     {$project:{ date:{$dateFromString:{dateString:'$date'}}}}
... ])
```

But it shows Error

```
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Error parsing date string '25/09/2019 16:37:56'; 0: Unexpected character '2'",
    "code" : 40553,
    "codeName" : "Location40553"
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:403:5
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1212:12
@(shell):1:1
```

I tried this also but it shows no format argument

```
db.firstcollection.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
        "date": { 
            "$dateFromString": { 
                "dateString": "$date",
                "format": "%d-%m-%Y %H%M%S" 
            } 
        }
    } }
])
```

I found that `MongoDB 3.6` has removed `format` argument in `dateFromString` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806248/why-am-i-getting-unrecognised-argument-to-datefromstring-format-despite-hav)So i can't specify the format.

I am also got confused with the manual of MongoDB 3.6

In first 3.6 manual link, it says format argument is there
[First Manual Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)
In another 3.6 manual link, it says no format argument
[Second Manual Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/#example)

So I don't know how to fix this problem. Suggest me some solutions to convert the `string` to `date` in `MongoDB`. I want to get data from MongoDB by using the `from and to date` specified. Since it is string, I can't get the proper data. Help me with some solutions

Comment: Use `%Y` specifier instead of `%G` as it represents to `ISO 8601`. https://mongoplayground.net/p/OcXrs4gY9Es

Comment: @Ashh, It shows `Unrecognized argument to $dateFromString: format"`

Comment: @Ashh, any other fix?

Comment: Upgrade to 4 and above can help. Nothing above than that.

Answer (score 4):

As you've tagged this with pymongo, the following is a quick approach:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime

db = MongoClient()['testdatabase']

db.testcollection.insert_one({
    "url" : "http://192.168.1.37/second.html",
    "browser" : "Netscape",
    "uniqueId" : "dd0c76b1-77c7-445a-8bcd-e58cb239507e",
    "ip" : " 162.158.166.103",
    "date" : "25/09/2019 16:37:56"
})
db.testcollection.insert_one({
    "url" : "http://192.168.1.37/second.html",
    "browser" : "Netscape",
    "uniqueId" : "c3a3c5f8-23a8-4626-9b43-b5a95fb02597",
    "ip" : " 172.69.134.115",
    "date" : "25/09/2019 16:38:13"
})

for item in db.testcollection.find():
    if 'date' in item:
        item['date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(item['date'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
        db.testcollection.replace_one({'_id': item['_id']}, item)
```

Result:

```
> db.testcollection.find({}, {'_id': 0}).pretty()
{
        "url" : "http://192.168.1.37/second.html",
        "browser" : "Netscape",
        "uniqueId" : "dd0c76b1-77c7-445a-8bcd-e58cb239507e",
        "ip" : " 162.158.166.103",
        "date" : ISODate("2019-09-25T16:37:56Z")
}
{
        "url" : "http://192.168.1.37/second.html",
        "browser" : "Netscape",
        "uniqueId" : "c3a3c5f8-23a8-4626-9b43-b5a95fb02597",
        "ip" : " 172.69.134.115",
        "date" : ISODate("2019-09-25T16:38:13Z")
}
```

Comment: Could you pls help on similar problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165765/mongodb-how-to-parse-date-in-3-6-mongodb-version